# How can I modify an existing table setting as auto increment the PK field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am finding some difficulties trying to modify a **MySql** table with an error.

This table have an **id** field that is setted as **PK**. The problem is that when this table was created this field was not setted as **auto increment**.

I tried also to remove this field and add it again setting it as autoincrement but I can't do it because this is used in other tables as FK, infact I am obtaining this error message:

```
#HY000Cannot drop column 'id': needed in a foreign key constraint 'FK_LivestockMessageDetails_LivestockMessage' of table 'digital_services_DB.LivestockMessageDetails'
while executing:
ALTER TABLE LivestockMessage
  DROP `id`,
  ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

I know that I can remove the FK, remove my **id** field and create it again as auto increment.

But how can I modify my table setting it as auto increment wothout do all this procedure?

Comment: Try this sql code : `ALTER TABLE `LivestockMessage` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL ;`

Comment: @KortebyFarouk error: #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: Or in Mysql Workbensh try to unselect the column AI in table configuration

Comment: Its should work even if they is data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the table and modify the column to include the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option?

```
ALTER TABLE LivestockMessage MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

*(The table will retain its `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `id`.)*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a1697/3

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the auto increment option :

```
ALTER TABLE `your_db`.`LivestockMessage` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Or using MySQL Work Bench select the AI option on the column configuration :

[image]

Comment: Updated the sql script